# jQuery is Conflicting with Media Upload Button in Pages in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have created the Multiple Image Upload Meta Fields ,
I am writting the jQuery code in theme's Functions.php ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            jQuery('#add-row').on('click', function() {
                var row = jQuery('.empty-row.screen-reader-text').clone(true);
                row.removeClass('empty-row screen-reader-text');
        row.insertAfter('#repeat_div table:last');
        return false;
            });

            jQuery('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
        jQuery(this).parents('table').remove();
        return false;
            });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.st_upload_button').click(function() {
         targetfield = jQuery(this).prev('.upload-url');
         tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
         return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
         imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
         jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
         tb_remove();
    }
});

</script>
```

But that code is conflicting with the Media Upload Button in wordpress, the image is not uploading,
How can i solve this, Guide me ASAP

Thanks 
Adeel

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this functionality using this script :

```
  /* include wordpress media uploader script */
  wp_enqueue_media();
```

---

```
 /* now html field and button   */ 
   <div class="uploader">
    <input id="_unique_name" name="settings[_unique_name]" type="text" />
    <input id="_unique_name_button" class="button" name="_unique_name_button" type="text" value="Upload" />
   </div>
   <div><img src="" width="100" id="testimage"></div>
```

---

```
   /*now scripts */
   <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function()
      {
       jQuery('#_unique_name_button').click(function()
        {
      wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment)
      {
        jQuery('#_unique_name').val(attachment.url);
        jQuery('#testimage').attr('src', attachment.url);
       }

      wp.media.editor.open(this);

       return false;
        });
      });
       </script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this , but its more conflicting then before. Add media media button completely stop 's working

Comment: I have used same code in my project, if you have some extra jquery scripts, Try again by deactivating them for a while.

Comment: Gopal i am Writting that code in functions.php .... may be you have used that code in custom pot type...........

Comment: thats is not a problem, I have used it in functions.php... You will have to check that what is conflicting actually.

Answer (score 0):

use `event.preventDefault()` in jquery .

```
        jQuery('.remove-row').on('click', function(e) {
    jQuery(this).parents('table').remove();
    e.preventDefaults();
    return false;
        });
```

[ref](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)